# Can't add or delete plugins - but I'm an admin

Tags: plugins, permissions

as the title says, I have Administrator privileges but I don't have the permission to add or delete plug-ins. (Button/Links just aren't on the page)

If I go to `.../wp-admin/plugin-install.php` I get the message:

`Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

**Edit:** And it is not a multisite and they did not have this problem a few days ago.

Also, I undertand the Yoast SEO plugin did not update properly - it threw an error (I don't know what unfortunately) and they replaced it via ftp

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Are you on a multisite? You might want to contact the person who set it up initially

Comment: Sorry - should have said - not a multisite!

Comment: Disable all your plugins via FTP and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: @rudtek - thank you - the issue was a funky file within the `wp-includes` folder - good advice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - I replaced the `wp-includes` folder with a fresh one, guest something funky was going down in there!

Comment: I'd suggest a close inspection of all folders; perhaps there is some malware files hiding in there? 
And I'd do a reinstall of WP via the Admin, Updates area, just to be sure all is well.

Comment: @RickHellewell not a bad idea!